# Can an inverted sentence start with an adjective?

Tags: grammar, inversion

The following sentence is cited from "gone with the wind":

> A little aloof, as became an aristocrat, lay a black-spotted carriage
>   dog, muzzle on paws, patiently waiting for the boys to go home to
>   supper.

Can someone refer to me some material on why the sentence can be phrased like that?

Answer (score -2):

That sentence is ungrammatical, IMO.   *A little aloof as became [i.e. befitted] an aristocrat* does not call for or "license" subject-verb inversion.

> A little aloof as became an aristocrat, did she enter the room. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> A little aloof as became an aristocrat, paid she no notice to the child begging for food. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> His mouth on fire from the hot pepper, took he a bite of bread. <sup>NO</sup>

If the first clause is an absolute construction, S-V inversion is not licensed in the main clause.

> A well regulated Militia being necessary to the security of a free State, shall the right of the people to keep and bear Arms not be infringed. <sup>NO</sup>

Comment: Reason for the downvote, please.